# How to check if an annotation of a class is of a particular category?

Tags: java, class, reflection

I have classes that are annotated as follows:

```
@BaseProp(category = Property.CATEGORY1)
where Property is a class defined as  
 public enum Property{
CATEGORY1("category1"), CATTEGORY2("category2");

    public static Property getCategory(String value) {
        return Property
                .valueOf(Optional.ofNullable(value).orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new).toUpperCase());
    }
```

It has appropriate getters, setters, constructors and this method `getCategory()`.

My other classes in multiple packages are annotated as

```
@Prop(category = Property.CATGORY1)
```

These classes extend a base class.

I want to create two `ArrayList` of objects for classes -
1. that extends BaseClass and category is annotated as CATEGORY1
2. that extends BaseClass and category is annotated as CATEGORY2

In the sense I want to identify the classes and create objects for them and put them in a general `ArrayList` of `Objectx`.

How can I do this using reflections and Java?

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. If you have a `Class`, checking for an annotation and its category is trivial. But first, you have to find out, how to find all subclasses of you base class. Then, how to create instances dynamically is another topic. But finding the subclasses is the hardest part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any class (e.g. Class X extends BaseClass), use something like:

```
Class<?> c = X.class;  // or if you have X x, then x.getClass();
for (Annotation ann : c.getAnnotations()) {
  if (ann instanceof BaseProp) {   // make sure it's your annotation
    BaseProp bp = (BaseProp)ann;
    bp.category();  // do something here
  }
}
```

You'll need to put your decision logic in the "// do something here" line by checking the actual property value there and then allocating the class to a list as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, how do I create an object for this class?

Comment: There is no need to iterate over all annotations. You can simply say `BaseProp bp = c.getAnnotation(BaseProp.class); if(bp!=null) {/* do something with */bp.category(); }`